# Is Bisquick used as a standard in recipes for shop-bound products?

Tags: baking, bread, flour

Are there shops that use Bisquick as a standard in their products that use flour mix?

I just noticed that Bisquick is a fragrant flour and seems of good quality. I thus suppose that for small retailers where freshly-milled flour is not as accessible, Bisquick can become an viable option for use in their baked goods.

I wonder if anyone has run the numbers on how much more expensive Bisquick is than making your own mix from scratch?

Or do they employ proprietary tech that allows them to source substandard flour but still pack it with the same aromatic quality?

-aspiring-baker, cafe-kiosk owner and start-up

Comment: I don't understand, why would the only choices be Bisquick and bad flour? Bisquick isn't special flour anyway, it's just totally normal flour with salt, baking powder, and shortening added. If that's the mix you want and for whatever reason it's hard to make it yourself, you might choose Bisquick, but it wouldn't be about flour quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are shops that use Bisquick. It is good.

On ingredient cost alone, I think a home made Bisquick substitute would save you 20% or so.

But there are hidden costs:

- Your time/labor cost weighing and mixing. You would have to cut in shortening..that equals cleaning labor time as well
- Your distraction. Fewer tasks = good.
- The likelihood your batches will be inconsistent (which will frustrate you and your customers)

Note:

- Supermarket Bisquick is in 2.5 lb packs
- You would probably want the [Sam's Club Bisquick 6 lb pack](http://www.samsclub.com/sams/bisquick-mix-96-oz/prod19541731.ip). That would probably be a good price point, and also pack size for a small shop.

Probably the best volume priced mix is Pillsbury "Hot Roll Mix" which they sell in 50 lb sacks. I magine the formula is similar to the supermarket mix.